# Regex search in PDF reader

Tags: regular-expression, pdf, zathura, documents, pdfgrep

I am using zathura, as I enjoy its minimalist approach, but I would also switch to mupdf or anything else if this would solve my problem.

I need to highlight every word (in PDF and epub documents) one by one from start to finish because I can concentrate better on the text if I have some kind of motion in it. My approach would have been to perform a regex search that matches every word, but neither zathura nor mupdf support regex in searches. Is there a way to do this?

I would try to fork zathura but to be honest I don't really want to spend that amount of time if there is another minimal Gnu/Linux compatible document viewer that does what I need. And if there is any way to use terminal tools like `pdfgrep` for highlighting the results in zathura that would also do the job.

Comment: `I need to highlight every word from start to finish` - may I ask what's the point of it?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Pretty simple, I can concentrate better when a cursor moves through text

Comment: So you don't want to highlight all the words at the same time but just a single word at a time? If so that needs to be implemented in the PDF reader.

Comment: Exactly, I see now that this isn't really clear from my question.

Comment: @luca you want to highlight the word the cursor sits on?

Comment: @vonbrand the word cursor was just the first word that came into my mind to describe something that moves through text, but I wasnt talking about _the_ cursor. I just want something that highlights every single word in a document, one word at a time and in the correct order.

Comment: @luca If you really want to, you can use `pdftotext` on your PDF and pipe the contents of the generated file into [speedread](https://github.com/pasky/speedread). The obvious downside is that you loose the markup.

Comment: @Devon Well I've already considered that but reading technical papers without proper formatting would be a real pain. So I guess I'll have to look for a better solution

Comment: "I see now that this isn't really clear from my question." -- did you know that you can [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/576734/edit) you question to make it clearer. As it stands I see nothing in the title or body of the question that is about what you want to do.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I do not think it is that important what I need it for but I have edited it anyway.

Comment: Your goal is the most important thing of all. All solutions that miss the goal will not be of help for you. **All** solutions that hit the goal will be of use to you.

Answer (score 4):

### Basic text selection

According to the [Zathura Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zathura_(document_viewer)):

> Zathura can search for text and copy text to the primary X selection

This implies the ability to select text as you read is built in, though it likely requires your mouse (you'll be hard-pressed to find a solution for keyboard-controlled selection).

How minimalist do you need? I use [Atril](https://github.com/mate-desktop/atril), a slightly lighter-weight fork of [Evince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evince) (the GNOME document viewer). Atril was made as part of the [MATE Desktop](https://mate-desktop.org/) (a continuation of GNOME 2). It's pretty light, though it does still have a GTK+ dependency.

Another option is [Xpdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpdf) application. See also [Wikipedia's List of PDF Software § Linux and Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Linux_and_Unix).

### Regex

The only (usable) regex search implementation I know of, aside form command-line tools like [pdfgrep](https://pdfgrep.org), is actually your web browser. This isn't so usable, but here's a solution in Firefox: Open a PDF in Firefox and open your Developer Tools Javascript Console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+K). Run these commands:

```javascript
» pdf = document.getElementById("viewer").innerText.replace(/[ \t]+/g, " ");
» function grep(what, context=100) { return pdf.match(RegExp(`[\\s\\S]{0,${context}}${what}[\\s\\S]{0,${context}}`), "img"); }
» grep("put your regex here")
» grep("get more context", 300)
```

Note that you'll have to escape your backslashes. The `grep` command has an optional second argument, the number of characters of context to provide on each side (default=100).

Chrome and other browsers with built-in PDF viewers should be rather similar, but you'll have to figure out what HTML object holds the actual PDF content (it's the `id="viewer"` element for Firefox, not sure about the others—in the worst case, just use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementById("viewer")`. You may match items in the table of contents.)

Comment: About the basic text selection: Yes zathura can do this, I knew about it. But I need the regex, which brings me to the second part of your answer. It is a solution although not the one I was looking for because it is a complex one, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Anyways, I gave you the bounty because you obviously did some work and technically  provided me a solution to my problem but I am still not marking this as solved because that is one hacky way to do it and I would honestly prefer an actual pdf reader instead of the browser. But thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistaken `Adobe Acrobat Reader` has a function called `read out loud` which selects each word from start to finish.

Comment: Thanks, but Adobe's Linux version is deprecated and thus contains countless security vulnerabilities, so not for me.